# sp_addlinkedsrvlogin / revert

Tags: sql, authentication, linked-server

I am a sysadmin on the two SQL server machines (obviously not a very good one). I linked the servers by using sp_addlinkedserver.  I was successful, and my query ran fine as T-SQL and a stored procedure. I tried to setup my stored procedure to run as a SQL Server Agent job. It was here that it was failing. I tried making a user on both servers the owner, but it was still failing. I did some reading and I wanted to add a mapped user. I ran the following command, not thinking it through, and now my user is messed up. I keep getting permission issues.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = 'servername', 
    @useself = 'true',
    @locallogin = 'null
```

How do I revert this back?  I tried dropping the linked server and logins... my user doesn't have that permission anymore. I can do that as Sa.  I can't add the linked server with my user anymore, gotta do that with sa.

Basically, how do I restore my permissions?  I'm still sysadmin in both SQL instances.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I did figure it out myself.  I logged in as SA to perform the following command.

```
EXEC sp_droplinkedsrvlogin
    @rmtsrvname = 'remoteserver',
    @locallogin = 'domain\user'
```

this did the trick, but I did have to close out of all active connections as the domain user, restart SSMS in order for me permissions to get returned.